# Editar o nome de um arquivo usando Python

Tags: python

estou trabalhando com centenas de arquivos pdf, eu tenho que renomea-los com o nome da pasta aonde eles estão alocados.

por exemplo:

```
pasta
  |--- pastajoão
           |-- celular.pdf
  |--- pastamaria
           |-- caderno.pdf
```

tem como usar o python para editar o nome dos arquivos deixando dessa maneira?:

```
pasta
  |--- pastajoão
           |-- pastajoão_celular.pdf
  |--- pastamaria
           |-- pastamaria_caderno.pdf
```

eu tenho esse código aqui:

```
    import pathlib import Path
    import os
    import shutil
    path = Path('meu caminho')
    for dirss in os.listdir(path=path):
    print(dirss)
    sleep(1)

    for dirs,  sub, files in os.walk(path):
        for file_ in files:
            path = os.path.join(dirs, file_)
            shutil.move(path, path)

    try:
        for _,  in path.glob('*.pdf'):
            edit = os.listdir()
            _.rename(edit)
    except Exception:
        print('Nenhum arquivo PDF')
```

ele me retorna esse erro

```
    for _,  in path.glob('*.pdf'):
    TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable PosixPath object
```

também se eu usar a função `rename()` ele va renomear o nome do arquivo inteiro, certo?

alguém poderia me ajudar ? :)

Comment: tem como usar o Python para editar o nome dos arquivos deixando dessa maneira?: Tem sim, porém o seu código há erros e posso estar enganado, mas não me parece que tentou resolver algo, e sim só copiou e colou e quer que alguém resolva o seu problema, caso edite e mostre interesse em algo mostrando que quer aprender eu volto para estar passando uma solução

Comment: isso é só um pedaço do meu código

Comment: eu só preciso editar o nome dos arquivos.

Comment: eu fiz várias pesquisas e não achei nada que poderia me ajudar e minhas souções deram errado também.

Comment: é que o código acima não demonstra que tenha algum tipo de conhecimento sobre a linguagem

Comment: @GuilhermeFrançadeOliveira eu editei minha postagem

Comment: tentando te ajudar postei abaixo algo que pode te da o resultado esperado, dê uma olhada e se resolver o seu problema é só marcar as repostas que forem uteis

Comment: O erro especifico está acontecendo por que você colocou uma `,` em `for _,  in path.glob('*.pdf'):`  - alias, por convençã,e m Python, usams `_` com um nome de variável apenas se for um "cesto de lixo" - isso é, um valor que é fornecido por efeito colateral em alguma chamada de função e não vai ser usado. Nesse caso é o seu objeto caminho_de_arquivo que você quer renomear - melhor dar um nome real pra variável.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OPÇÃO 1:**

Você pode tentar algo como:

```
import os
def change_file_name(sufix, path):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        prefix = path.split("\\")[-1] + "_" #Armazena o nome da pasta atual
        if file.endswith(sufix) and not file.startswith(prefix):
            #Verifica se o arquivo tem o sufixo procurado e se o arquivo
            #não foi alterado anteriormente.
            os.rename(path + "\\" + file, path + "\\" + prefix + file)

    print(os.listdir(my_path))

sufix = ".pdf"
path = r"c:\my\choosed\path"

change_file_name(sufix, path)
```

Claro, daí você já pode fazer tua customização para adequar a complexidade do teu sistema, porém a base para fazer uma mudança seria +- esse código acima.

**OPÇÃO 2:**

Você joga uma pasta 'pai' e vai mapeando nas pastas 'filhas' os arquivos.

```
import os
def change_file_name(sufix, path):
    for files in os.walk(path):
        prefix = files[0].split("\\")[-1] + "_" #Armazena o nome da pasta atual

        for file in files[2]: #Passa arquivo por arquivo dentro da pasta
            if file.endswith(sufix) and not file.startswith(prefix):
                #Verifica se o arquivo tem o sufixo procurado e se o arquivo
                #não foi alterado anteriormente.
                os.rename(files[0] + "\\" + file, files[0] + "\\" + prefix + file)

        print(files,"\n")

sufix = ".pdf"
path = r"c:\my\choosed\parent\path"

change_file_name(sufix, path)
```

Neste caso, segundo o teu exemplo

```
pasta
  |--- pastajoão
           |-- celular.pdf
  |--- pastamaria
           |-- caderno.pdf
```

Você só precisaria passar o diretório 'pasta', pois 'pastajoão' e 'pastamaria' passariam automaticamente na função 'os.walk()', assim você só passa o diretório raiz (ou pai) e os demais diretórios serão mapeados de forma autônoma.

Comment: Fiz algumas edições para deixar o código mais completo.
Ele recebe um sufixo para procurar, como ".pdf" por exemplo.
Também passa o diretório em que deseja alterar o arquivo.

Comment: oi o código não editou os arquivos ele continua como estão

Comment: Fiz uma edição, colocando duas opções. Poderia confirmar se funcionou? Ou se apresentou algum erro?

Comment: obrigado amigo, funionou corretamente

Answer (score 0):

seguindo o seu código fiz essa pequena modificação

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

path = Path('diretorio')
try:
    for _ in path.glob('*.pdf'):
        new_name = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(_))
        print(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(new_name), new_name))
        _.rename(f'{os.path.join(os.path.abspath(new_name), new_name)}_{os.path.basename(_)}')
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
    print('Nenhum arquivo PDF')
```

algo que reparei que você esta usando o `import pathlib import Path` e o correto seria `from pathlib import Path`

Comment: oi guilherme o código não conseguiu editar os arquivos

Comment: colocou o caminho de onde estão os arquivos?

Comment: sim, coloquei sim

Comment: me passa o erro que apareceu para você, por aqui fiz uma emulação e correspondeu com o resultado

Comment: se puder me forneça o seu sistema operacional também

Comment: ele retornou nenhum error, simplemente não editou o arquivo

Comment: eu estou usando Ubuntu 19

Comment: fiz alguns teste ele me retornou isso expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Comment: Então vamos tentar achar o problema primeiro, você estar utilizando o caminho completo da pasta tipo, `/home/user/Documentos/pastadestino`? ou só uma parte? os arquivos que concede permissão para editar os arquivos? se puder mostre o que aparece quando você da `ls -l` na pasta que quer editar

Comment: o erro que me forneceu diz não pode se uma tupla, provavelmente você esta colocando algum item em alguma tupla, vou pensa em algo que mostre o erro de onde ele vem, mas tente usar um caminho completo como disse acima `path = Path('/home/user/Documentos/pastadestino')`